# C# - setting rule to prevent certain attributes/classes from being used

Tags: c#, warnings, editorconfig

I use sonarcloud which seems to take into account some settings in my .editorconfig file. I have an issue with some people misusing certain attributes to the point where I would like to flag it as a warning if a certain attribute is being used. In this case, the attribute name is so specific that even a regex check to see if any files contain `MySuperSpecificAttributeNameHere` at all. Is there any way that I can use the editorconfig or add a custom rule in sonar to flag any files containing this string? I just need to be able to label them as warnings somehow.

Comment: Is this an attribute made in your code, or from a 3rd party library or the runtime?

Comment: @gunr2171 it's one of the DataAnnotations

Comment: Also interesting for the `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` attribute being abused so sonar will always use the file for code coverage